# How to publish to AWS S3 using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, amazon-s3

I have S3, and I want a built in or any easy option to publish certain static content directly to the S3 via my visual studio.

Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a post build task (AfterBuild) using exec task with winscp.

winscp sftp://root:password;@myip:myport/hostdir/ myfile.zip

where myip is your amazons ip address, myport is the port and hostdir is the location on your host.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx
ref: http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Comment: No, I don't think S3 exposes an FTP or SFTP interface. An AfterExec task is the right idea, but you couldn't use an sftp protocol, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Sorry I missed the s3 bit.. then can you use something like the s3cmd tool @ http://s3tools.org/s3cmd or s3cp @  http://www.beaconhill.com/opensource/s3cp.html or s3 @
http://s3.codeplex.com/